# Which free tool for Windows can save the preferred positions of GUI apps?

Tags: windows, desktop

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I am looking for a free tool.

I start a number of batch jobs running inside command prompt. I want to shrink them significantly, so that I can see the Window titles only. I usually shrink them by hand and move them to another monitor.

I am looking for a tool that can do that work for me as soon as certain apps start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about "GUI apps" but if the command prompts are being started by a shortcut you can modify the shortcut, pick window sizes and positions, and then have Windows modify that shortcut so they stick for future launches.

Basically right-click the command prompt's title bar, pick properties, and then adjust things under the Layout tab.

There's some info/instruction on it (with pictures) [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/46756-window-text-size-command-prompt-windows-xp-mode.html#post442069) that should get you underway.

HTH.